# VBA: Class Module: Get and Let

Tags: vba, class

I have no experience with custom classes and a really simple question, but I found it difficult to google this:

I've come across an example ([source](https://www.excelanytime.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=160:excel-vba-custom-classes-a-objects-class-modules-custom-events&catid=79&Itemid=475)) for using custom classes.

**Module 1**

```
Sub clsRectAreaRun()
'This procedure instantiates an instance of a class, sets and calls class properties.

Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double

Dim areaRect As New clsRectArea

a = InputBox("Enter Length of rectangle")
b = InputBox("Enter Width of rectangle")

areaRect.Length = a
areaRect.Width = b

MsgBox areaRect.rArea

End Sub
```

**class module 'clsRectArea'**

```
'Example - Create Read-Only Class Property with only the PropertyGet_EndProperty block.
Private rectL As Double
Private rectW As Double

Public Property Let Length(l As Double)
     rectL = l
End Property

Public Property Get Length() As Double
    Length = rectL
End Property

Public Property Let Width(w As Double)
   rectW = w
End Property

Public Property Get Width() As Double
    Width = rectW
End Property

Public Property Get rArea() As Double
'Read-Only property with only the PropertyGet_EndProperty block and no PropertyLet_EndProperty (or PropertySet_EndProperty) block.
    rArea = Length * Width
End Property
```

My question is regarding this part of the code:

```
areaRect.Length = a
areaRect.Width = b

MsgBox areaRect.rArea 'rArea = Length * Width
```

From what I've read, that `Get` and `Let` properties have the same name is kind of the point. But I have to ask, how does the code know if it's supposed to call `Get` or `Let`? Is it simply down to if, in this case, `Length` and `Width` are to the left or to the right of the equal sign? As in, when you want to assign a value to the property, it automatically recognizes it's `Let` and if it's on the right, like for `rArea` here, the code is supposed to retrieve the value, so it's `Get`?

I know, extremely basic, but I'm not 100% sure and I simply want to know if I'm not messing up the something basic.

Comment: Assigning a value is ```let``` or ```set``` if an object. Retrieving the value is ```get```.

Comment: [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Classes.aspx#:~:text=First%2C%20insert%20a%20class%20module,private%20variables%20within%20the%20class.) is a pretty good tutorial on classes in VBA.

Comment: @Warcupine Thank you! Can I close my own question somehow or just vote for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convince yourself which property method is being called by adding `MsgBox`'s to the code in the class module.

For example:

```
Public Property Let Length(l As Double)
     rectL = l
     MsgBox "Let Length called."
End Property
```